# How to bulk replace empty body tag (</TextView>) with empty end tag (/>)

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I have got a project made in some old version of Eclipse. It is full of empty body tags, such as

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
```

I want to convert it to a empty end tag, which is the way I prefer. Want to get end tags like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Android Studio highlights empty body tag items and it can automatically convert it to empty end tag (`Alt+Enter`-> Replace Tag Empty Body With Empty End), but I have to do it one by one.

I tried highlighting all such widgets and pressed `Alt+Enter`, and it showed the same command, but pressing it would change only the first widget in the selection. I expected that all highlighted elements would be changed.

How can I bulk convert all widgets with empty body tag to empty end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another menu in which is not visible by default. After you press `Alt+Enter`, navigate to `Replace Tag Empty Body With Empty End`, then **press right-arrow key** on your keyboard to show submenu, and then select "Fix all XML tag empty body problems."

[image]

Too bad that this menu is hard to notice as I spent hours and hours fixing these issues by hand.